# Call two services in the same time

Tags: angular

When  `submit =True`  my form, I create my element in the database in back end (spring boot + postgres), The function create1 return number but it is of type any I use this number there to create another element with the function create. The problem is that this part

```
this.analysefnc.n_fnc =data;
  this.analysefnc.statut="A créer";
  this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc);
```

is not executed in the code.

Full code :

```
onsubmit(){
  this.submitted=true;
  this.fnc.etat="en cours";

  this.fncservice.create1(this.fnc).subscribe((data)=> {
    console.log("data", data);
    this.analysefnc.n_fnc =data;
    this.analysefnc.statut="A créer";
    this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc);
  }, error => console.error(error));
```

Create1 Function :

```
 create1(data): any  {
  this.http.post(baseUrl, data, { responseType: 'text'})
   .subscribe((res) => {
   //response will be parsed as text and we need to convert it to int
   const resInt = + res;   
   console.log(resInt);         
   return resInt;
   },(error) => {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Function Create :

```
create(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
}
```

Console error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
  create1(data): any {
    return this.http.post<number>(baseUrl, data).pipe(map(res => {
      const resInt = +res;
      console.log(resInt);
      return resInt;
    }),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: doesn"t reconigze res variable

Comment: try again, I modified my answer as it was bad formatted

Answer (score 1):

Your create1 function is returning an Int but it should return an Observable so please change:

```
create1(data): Observable<any>{
  this.http.post(baseUrl, data, { responseType: 'text'})
   .subscribe((res) => {
   //response will be parsed as text and we need to convert it to int
   const resInt = + res;   
   console.log(resInt);         
   return of(resInt);
   },(error) => {
  console.log(error);
  return throwError(error);
 });
```

You need to Subscribe

```
this.fncservice.create1(this.fnc).subscribe(
  (data)=> {
  console.log("data", data);
  this.analysefnc.n_fnc =data;
  this.analysefnc.statut="A créer";
         this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc).subscribe((data) => {
//Your code here
}, error => console.error(error));
  },error=>console.error(error)
  );
```

However it’s better to use “switchmap” to avoid this Nested Observable pattern.

```
this.fncservice.create1(this.fnc).pipe(
      switchmap((data)=> {
          console.log("data", data);
          this.analysefnc.n_fnc =data;
          this.analysefnc.statut="A créer";
          return this.analyseFncService.create(this.analysefnc)
          })
       ). subscribe((data) => {
          //Your code here
       }, error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: I did but still the same prblm

Comment: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.

Comment: Then the title of your question is misleading. This is not related to “calling two services at the same time”.

Comment: Yes , I tried to describe the prblm , I used "SwitchMap" and I get this error core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at CreationFncComponent.onsubmit (creation-fnc.component.ts:63)

Comment: Edited my answer. Does it work now? You were returning a number but you need to return a number wrapped in an Observable

Comment: I got two errors in function create 1 
1 - Cannot find name 'of'.ts(2304)
2-A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355)

Comment: Please share the errors to see if they are related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226508/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-victor-martinez-calvo).

Comment: Are you importing “of” ? Import {of} from 'rxjs'

Comment: No , he don"t give me the suggestion to import maybe I need to install smthing ?

Answer (score 1):

`create1(this.fnc)` should return an `Observable` otherwise the `subscribe` as:

```
this.fncservice.create1(this.fnc).subscribe
```

will not work

```js
 create1(data): Observable<any> {
  this.http.post(baseUrl, data, { responseType: 'text'})
   .subscribe((res) => {
   //response will be parsed as text and we need to convert it to int
   const resInt = + res;   
   console.log(resInt);         
   return resInt;
   },(error) => {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: I update the function but give me this error A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: Yes of course then return a value from that function

Comment: I return resInt ??"   return resInt;
"

Comment: you have to return an error as well in case you have an error, but you are not doing it

Comment: I did but still the same problem (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return error;

Comment: you may have an issue in another place, edit and put your complete code, creating a stackblitz to reproduce the error will help people to understand your issue more as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226507/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-hdjemai).

Comment: But  I think the function create1 is is separated of my code , they say that the function must return a value when she have the type osbervable<x>

Comment: when a function needs to return an observable you have to do so, return `Observable.of(...)` or just `return of(...)`

Comment: I  used 
      return throwError(error); but still have the prblm in Observable<number>